# Ruby return statement not working

Tags: ruby, recursion, data-structures, graph, return

I've been trying to make a graph data structure that finds kevin bacon. I've had an issue with my return statement not working and I was wondering what the issue might be. Here is my code and thanks for any help in advance:

```
require_relative "Node"

$films = []
$actors = []

def find_kevin_bacon(node, start)
  $actors << start.name

  if start.name == "Kevin Bacon"
    puts "YES!"
    return $films
  end

  if start.name != "Kevin Bacon"
    puts "NO!"

    start.film_actor_hash.each do |movie, actors|
      if actors.include?(node)
        puts "Its Him!"
        $films << movie
        find_kevin_bacon(node,node)
      end
    end

    start.film_actor_hash.each do |movie, actors|
      if $films.include?(movie) == false

        actors.each do |act|
          if $actors.include?(act) == false
            $films << movie
            find_kevin_bacon(node, act)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  $films
end
```

I inserted a few puts statements to see my output and when I run it I get the following:

```
NO!
NO!
NO!
NO!
Its Him!
YES!
NO!
NO!
NO!
NO!
NO!
Chappie
X2
Robots
Footloose
Robots
X2
Chappie
Lion
Bewitched
```

So the code indicated that "Kevin Bacon" was included in one of the nodes actors array, however instead of ending the method it continues to go on.   Once again thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recursive method there needs to be a "base case" - in which it does not fire a recursive call, but returns something instead. One way to do this would be the following:

1. Instead of `$films`, return nil at the end of the method. In effect, this is a way to signal *this iteration did not find the solution*.
2. In the places where you run `find_kevin_bacon(node,node)` or `find_kevin_bacon(node,act)`, instead do this:

   ```
   result = find_kevin_bacon(node, node) # or node, act
   return result if result
   ```

   That second line will not only stop the loop, it will return from the whole method.

Comment: I used the second option you suggested and it worked, so thank you for that. I am curious though,  so my understanding is that with the return result if result is in the format of return "code" if "condition". So how does the "condition" equal true, typically wouldn't you need to compare something in the if statement to get a boolean value of true or false?

Comment: That list is not two options. Both parts are necessary.